# Matrix manipulation for Dirac matrices

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, dirac-equation

From the Dirac equation in gamma matrices, we know that $$\gamma^i=\begin{pmatrix}
  0 & \sigma^i \\
  -\sigma^i & 0
 \end{pmatrix}$$ and $$\gamma^0=\begin{pmatrix}
  I & 0 \\
  0 & -I
 \end{pmatrix}$$
Now what do we understand by this operation $\gamma^0 \gamma^{\mu \star}\gamma^0 =\gamma^{\mu T}$

Do we have to verify the above equation by doing matrix operation details? or anything short important idea can do this quickly.

Comment: What do you mean by `anything short important idea can do this quickly.`?

Comment: I meant that If i could understand the equation $\gamma^0 \gamma^{\mu \star} \gamma^0 = \gamma^{\mu T}$ without doing the matrix multiplication elaborately.

Comment: Related question by OP: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/48334/2451