# To construct a Lorentz scalar we use $\psi^{\dagger}\gamma^{0}\psi$. Could we use $\gamma^{5}$ instead of $\gamma^{0}$ seen as both are Hermitian?

Tags: special-relativity, dirac-equation, spinors, dirac-matrices

Both $\gamma^{0}$ and $\gamma^{5}$ are Hermitian, so could we replace $\gamma^{0}$ with $\gamma^{5}$ to construct a Lorentz scalar with the same properties as $\bar{\psi}\psi$?

Comment: What's stopping you from calculating how it transforms?

Comment: @JamalS This is as good as a pithy short answer. The OP might have no idea...

Comment: @JamalS I have tried to calculate it myself, though I am not sure of my conclusion. My guess is that it does not form a Lorentz scalar because the transformation uses the fact that $\gamma^{0} \gamma^{0} = 1$, but this is not the case for $\gamma^{5}$?
EDIT: $\gamma^{5}$ does have this property - so it should be able to take the role of $\gamma^{0}$ and construct a Lorentz scalar right?

Answer (score 3):

A Lorentz boost about the $i$th spatial direction is represented as $\psi\rightarrow V\psi$ with $V=\exp\left(\theta[\gamma^0,\gamma^i]\right)$ for some real $\theta$. The problem is that $V^\dagger\neq V^{-1}$. This follows since $\gamma^0$ is Hermitian and $\gamma^i$ is anti-Hermitian, which implies that $$[\gamma^0,\gamma^i]^\dagger=[\gamma^{i\dagger},\gamma^{0\dagger}]=+[\gamma^0,\gamma^i]$$ whereas we would want a minus sign for $V$ to be unitary.

Using $\gamma^0$ in $\psi^\dagger\gamma^0\psi$ gives us that extra minus sign we need which comes from commuting $\gamma^0$ past the factor of $\gamma^i$ in the exponent. Using $\gamma^5$ instead would not work since it gives us two minus signs from commuting past both $\gamma^0$ and $\gamma^i$ in the exponent.

Answer (score 3):

Of course you can, just a bit different from yours. The following is a Lorentz scalar and Hermitian:
$$
\bar{\psi}i\gamma^{5}\psi = \psi^{\dagger}i\gamma^{0}\gamma^{5}\psi = -\psi^{\dagger}\gamma^{1}\gamma^{2}\gamma^{3}\psi.
$$

It's called "pseudoscalar" mass term. See more details [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/611255/is-there-a-square-root-of-klein-gordon-equation-which-is-different-from-dirac#611255).

Comment: So just to be clear, no you can not replace $\gamma^0$ by $\gamma^5$ to get a scalar. (I upvoted anyway)