# What is the correct relation between Dirac matrices and Charge conjugation?

Tags: dirac-matrices, charge-conjugation

#### Setup

Let $C$ be the charge conjugation operator for spinors and $\gamma$ a Dirac matrix. From [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/48334/charge-conjugation-in-dirac-equation) post we conclude that the critical relation between the operator and the Dirac matrices is
$$-C(\gamma^\mu)^*C^{-1}=\gamma^\mu.\tag{1}$$
[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_matrices#Charge_conjugation) on the other hand states that
$$-C(\gamma^\mu)^T C^{-1}=\gamma^\mu.\tag{2}$$

#### Question

Are these two statements equivalent?

#### My attempt at showing they are

Let's take $(1)$ and transpose it
$$\begin{align*}
(\gamma^\mu)^T&= -(C(\gamma^\mu)^*C^{-1})^T =-(C^{-1})^T(\gamma^\mu)^\dagger C^T =-C(\gamma^\mu)^\dagger C^{-1}\\
&=-C\gamma^0\gamma^\mu\gamma^0 C^{-1},
\end{align*}$$
where we have used $C^{-1}=C^T=C^\dagger=-C$ in the Dirac, Majorana and Weyl basis. We now fix the basis to Dirac, so that $C=i\gamma^2\gamma^0$. Inserting this in the previous result we get
$$\begin{align*}
(\gamma^\mu)^T&=-C\gamma^0\gamma^\mu\gamma^0 C^{-1} 
= -(i\gamma^2\gamma^0)\gamma^0\gamma^\mu\gamma^0 (-i\gamma^2\gamma^0)= -i\gamma^2\gamma^\mu i\gamma^2\\ 
&\neq -C^{-1}\gamma^\mu C,
\end{align*}$$
where the last line is equivalent to $(2)$. Since the equivalence doesn't hold in the Dirac basis, it shouldn't hold in any other basis either.

So it seems these statements are not equivalent, but in that case I wonder which of the two is true? And why?

Answer (score 1):

The definition of the charge transformation matrix on Wikipedia is correct.
Actually, it cannot be easily transformed into the first one, a relation like $\gamma^{\mu\dagger} =\gamma^\mu$ would make that possible. But this is wrong.

For $\gamma$-matrices we have $\gamma^{\mu\dagger} = \gamma^0\gamma^\mu \gamma^0$.